# QuickFix Python API - possible to subclass MessageStoreFactory in Python?

Tags: python, swig, quickfix

How do you subclass the MessageStoreFactory class in Python when using the Python bindings for QuickFix?

When I attempt this the object is not "seen" as a MessageStoreFactory:

```
NotImplementedError: Wrong number of arguments for overloaded function  'new_SocketInitiatorBase'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
FIX::SocketInitiator(FIX::Application &,FIX::MessageStoreFactory &,FIX::SessionSettings const &)
FIX::SocketInitiator(FIX::Application &,FIX::MessageStoreFactory &,FIX::SessionSettings const &,FIX::LogFactory &)
```

This error seems to be returned by SWIG when the types are wrong.  (I've only used Boost  in the past - is subclassing of a C++ class in Python even possible in SWIG?)

**Updated**
The Python bindings are the ones packaged for Ubuntu 12.04.  I'm fairly sure I've got the arguments correct as the error only occurs when I swap out one of the QuickFix objects with the one below when I create a SocketInitiator:

```
class TestStoreFactory(quickfix.MessageStoreFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.info("TestStoreFactory()")

    def create(self, sessionId):
        logging.info("Create %s"%sessionId)

    def destroy(self, messageStore):
        logging.info("Destroy %s" % messageStore)
```

Comment: According to thee documentation it is possible to subclass a [C++ class from Python](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_directors), I have only done this with Java and it worked great. In the QuickFix page I have only seen links for the Java and .Net bindings, where did you get them for Python?. And the obvious questions, are you calling the function with the correct number of arguments?, could you post that code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Got around this problem by placing a call to the base class constructor.

```
class TestStoreFactory(quickfix.MessageStoreFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        quickfix.MessageStoreFactory.__init__(self)
        logging.info("TestStoreFactory()")
```